# TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null ; temperatureDegree.textContent = temperature

Tags: javascript

I am making a weather app and cannot edit the "textContent" without an error coming up on the line: temperatureDegree.textContent = temperature

```
window.addEventListener("load", ()=> {
    let long
    let lat
    let temperatureDescription = document.querySelector("temperature-description")
    let temperatureDegree = document.querySelector("temperature-degree")
    let locationTimezone = document.querySelector("location-timezone")

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
            long = position.coords.longitude
            lat = position.coords.latitude

            const proxy = "http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"
            const api = `${proxy}https://api.darksky.net/forecast/503a88031807535a11c0654c147002d5/${lat},${long}`
            fetch(api)
            .then(response => {
                return response.json()
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data)
                const {temperature, summary} = data.currently
                //Set DOM Elements from the API
                temperatureDegree.textContent = temperature
            })
        })
    } else {
        h1.textContent = "We can't find your location...make sure it is activated."
    }
})
```

Comment: Show us to your `HTML` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to precede the selector symbol. If *temperature-degree* is an *id* then precede that with hash (`#`) symbol

```
let temperatureDegree = document.querySelector("#temperature-degree")
```

Or if it is a *class* then precede that with dot (`.`) symbol

```
let temperatureDegree = document.querySelector(".temperature-degree")
```

You have to to do the same for other elements as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `Class` for selecting `DOM` element, Use

```
let temperatureDegree = document.querySelector(".temperature-degree");
```

If you use `id`, Use

```
let temperatureDegree = document.querySelector("#temperature-degree");
```